# Delayed job exclude queue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I have a delayed job queue which contains particularly slow running tasks, which I want to be crunched by its own set of dedicated workers, so there is less risk it'll bottleneck the rest of the worker pipeline.

`RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job --queue=super_slow_stuff start`

However I then also want a general worker pool for all other queues, hopefully without having to specify them seperately (as their names etc are often changed/added too). Something akin to:

`RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job --except-queue=super_slow_stuff start`

I could use the wildcard `*` charecter but I imagine this would cause the second worker to pickup the super slow jobs too?

Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 1):

you can define a global constant for your app with all queues.

```
QUEUES={
  mailers: 'mailers',
  etc..
}
```

then use this constant in yours delay method calls

```
object.delay(queue: QUEUES[:mailers]).do_something
```

and try to build delayed_job_args dinamically

```
system("RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job --pool=super_slow_stuff --pool:#{(QUEUES.values-[super_slow_stuff]).join(',')}:number_of_workers start")
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this functionality not realized in delayed jobs.

See:

https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/pull/466

https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/pull/901

You may fork delayed jobs repository and apply the simple patches from https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/pull/466.

Then use your GitHub repo, but please vote into https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/pull/466 to make it merged finally into upstream.

**Update:**
I wrote option to exclude queues for myself. It is in (exclude_queues) branch: https://github.com/one-more-alex/delayed_job/tree/exclude_queues 
https://github.com/one-more-alex/delayed_job_active_record/tree/exclude_queues

Options description included in Readme.md

Parts about exclusion.

```
# Option --exclude-specified-queues will do inverse of queues processing by skipping onces from --queue, --queues.
# If both --pool=* --exclude-specified-queues given, no exclusions will by applied on "*".
```

```
If EXCLUDE_SPECIFIED_QUEUES set to YES, then queues defined by QUEUE, QUEUES will be skipped instead. See opton --exclude-specified-queues description for specal case of queue "*"
```

If answer strictly on question, the calling of general worker will be like:

```
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job --queue=super_slow_stuff --exclude-specified-queues start
```

**Warning**
Please not, that am not going to support DelayedJobs and code placed "as is" in hope it will be useful.
Corresponding pull request was made by me https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/pull/1019

Also for Active Record backend: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job_active_record/pull/151

Only ActiveRecord backend supported.

Comment: There is one more question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073051/exclude-queue-from-delayed-job-worker

Comment: That was just a link for similar/duplicate question.

Comment: What a reason to down vote? @SirRawlins asked for suggestions. I made exactly corresponding suggestions. Also made a big work to solve it for my self. If so... welcome to down vote...