# Exclude queue from delayed_job worker

Tags: ruby, delayed-job

In delayed_jobs it is possible to run a worker for a specific queues. I can't seem to find any examples/documentation on how to run a worker and exclude a specific queue.

I am trying to have 1 worker for super high priority stuff and 1 that handles the rest.

Is the only way to achieve this by specifying what queues relate to what worker? Is there no way to spawn a worker that runs all queues except queue_x?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delayed job exclude queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44808629/delayed-job-exclude-queue)